# Apple Music: Heart ratings ("Loved" tracks) are not supposed to synchronize between devices?

Tags: iphone, itunes, music, apple-music, ratings

I hearted/Loved dozens of tracks on Apple Music desktop (on Mac), but when I played them on my iPhone, they were not hearted/Loved.

Is it normal? I hope not, because it wouldn't make any sense! (Why would I want to love a track but only on one device and not on another?)

If it is indeed normal, is there a way to force this sync?

Thanks!

Comment: You can create a Smart Playlist for Loved tracks but this only applies to tracks that have been adding to your library. I also hope this is a bug they will iron out.

Comment: Yes, I figured this much. I don't mind having to add to the library first. The thing is, the smart playlist is only populated on my mac, not on my phone.

Comment: I'm finding that nothing synchronizes between my Mac and iPhone. My guess is the hearted status is just a symptom of synchronizing not working.

Comment: @Jon But my manual playlists get synced normally whenever I add or removed songs. It works both ways. Only the Heart status (and the smart playlist that depends on it) has an issue.

Comment: I have a similar problem but not quite, I heart music, sync with say my ipod or iPhone and after its complete all the songs unheard, could this be connected in someway cause its getting annoying having to reheart the same songs atleast once a day

Answer (score 4):

Through investigating a [similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/195653/create-a-playlist-of-songs-loved-likes-on-itunes-radio/195655#195655) I have found the same thing, you don't appear to be able to create a Smart Playlist for online content.

However if you download the song for offline playback you can `Love` it and it will show in the Smart Playlist of `Loved` songs. However this playlist does not sync to an iOS device, regardless of it being in offline storage on your iOS device.

I imagine this is a bug, and certainly isn't very user friendly. People are becoming confused by the fact you can `Love` a song but it doesn't let you review a list of `Loved` songs later.

I would expect an update in future to resolve this, seems like a lack of UX design and testing in Apple Music as there are a few issues like this.

Comment: Is this fixed yet? There's essentially no way I could stop using Spotify in favour of this until that happens...

Comment: Did anyone find a solution? I'm seriously considering switching to Spotify because of this...