# Create a playlist of songs loved/likes on Apple Music

Tags: itunes, ios, itunes-radio

I've been listening to the Apple Music thing that came out in iOS 8.4 and I've been clicking the little heart button on the songs I've liked assuming I'd be able to find these songs again.

Is there anyway to get a list/playlist of the songs I've clicked the heart button for?

Comment: Kinda funny. Once I hit the like button they make a point of never ever playing it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of people are making this mistake at the moment, the like/love button in Apple Music is not for creating a playlist.

It's there to tune the 'For You' section in Apple Music to your tastes so it can better make suggestions of what music you should try out next.

**EDIT**

As you've pointed out in your comment there is an ability to create a smart playlist of `Loved` songs in iTunes, however this is only referring to songs that you've Loved that are physically in your iTunes library, i.e. songs that you bought or ripped from a CD.

It is confusing but `Loved` in your iTunes library is unrelated to `Loved` in Apple Music.

**EDIT 2**

I've been playing some more and I managed to get the Playlist to include a song I `Loved` once I had downloaded it for offline playback in iTunes and then marked it. However this doesn't sync to my iPhone through iCloud Playlist Sync.

Comment: I know it tunes it but it would make sense to at least let us see the list o.o There is some option in the iTunes (desktop version) to create a smart playlist which selects the song which is like/loved but it doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: I've updated to answer your point.

Comment: You must "Add to My Music" for the song to appear in the Smart Playlist. The song doesn't need to be downloaded to your library to appear in the playlist when you do that.

Answer (score 1):

i did this by in itunes, my top rated playlist, edit and select lovedfrom the drop down :) Itunes on the computer not Ipod/Phone