# How Does iTunes Sync Loved Metadata?

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, apple-music

A tcpdum of "loving" a song on iTunes yields an empty ppcap file. Is the data cached and synced later? If so, when and where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/194022/apple-music-heart-ratings-loved-tracks-are-not-supposed-to-synchronize-betw)

I believe it is a server side stored field.
I do not believe it is suppose to sync (even though it would be nice)

If you want to keep track of the music you "love" I would recommend just adding to a playlist.